# Fresh centOS 6.3 server from Amazon Ec2...is there a default password? What would it be?

Tags: centos, password

After getting through known_hosts issues, it's now asking for a password. I don't recall setting a password..what would it be?

Answer (score 3):

There is no password set, by default it will only accept your private key.
See also: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AccessingInstancesLinux.html

Answer (score 0):

No password is necessary across all AWS instances. Use your private KEY to login. If you do not have the key, then there is way to gain access to your instances, but that's a lengthy workaround; think Eric Hammond blogged about this somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

**For CentOS 7.x** You can set root password for EC2 after first time login with your **.pem** file.

After login just type `sudo passwd` and it will ask new password for **root** user.

Sometime it will be necessary to change your root password by yourselves no matter how you will logged in future.